visualization of CMIP6 data
Currently trying to visualize the temperature of a very small area near the Earth's surface. Yet the scale bar besides the image still portrays the complete temperature range of the whole atmsophere, instead of detailing the specific part that is shown on the image. How do I interact with this scale bar, so it only shows the limits of the image values.
(https://i.sstatic.net/mLKOvSKD.png)
Currently trying to visualize the temperature of a very small area near the Earth's surface.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
